# Evaluate ROC AUC for Keras sequential multiclass model

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I want to evaluate the ROC AUC for my multiclass sequential Keras model using the `multiclass_roc_auc_score` function. My code raised `ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible`.

I want to perform multiclass classification:

```
class MulticlassTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='multiclass_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, 'int32') == tf.cast(y_pred, 'int32')
        values = tf.cast(values, 'float32')
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, 'float32')
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_states(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)
```

I compile the Keras model with the metrics:

```
# Report the AUC of a model outputting a probability.
hypermodel.compile(optimizer='sgd',
              loss=tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy(),
              metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), MulticlassTruePositives()])
```

I implement Keras callback that plots the ROC curve and Confusion Matrix to a folder:

```
class PerformanceVisualizationCallback(Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, test_data, image_dir):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.test_data = test_data
        
        os.makedirs(image_dir, exist_ok=True)
        self.image_dir = image_dir

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = np.asarray(self.model.predict(self.test_data[0]))
        y_true = self.test_data[1]             
        y_pred_class = np.argmax(y_pred, axis=1)

        # plot and save confusion matrix
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
        plot_confusion_matrix(y_true, y_pred_class, ax=ax)
        fig.savefig(os.path.join(self.image_dir, f'confusion_matrix_epoch_{epoch}'))

       # plot and save roc curve
        fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(16,12))
        plot_roc(y_true, y_pred, ax=ax)
        fig.savefig(os.path.join(self.image_dir, f'roc_curve_epoch_{epoch}'))

performance_viz_cbk = PerformanceVisualizationCallback(
                                       model=model,
                                       test_data=X_test,
                                       image_dir='perorfmance_charts')

history = hypermodel.fit(x=X_train,
                    y=y_train,
                    epochs=5,
                    callbacks=[performance_viz_cbk])
```

Traceback:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ValueError                                Traceback (most recent call last)
/tmp/ipykernel_17/963709483.py in <module>
      2                     y=y_train,
      3                     epochs=5,
----> 4                     callbacks=[performance_viz_cbk])

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, validation_batch_size, validation_freq, max_queue_size, workers, use_multiprocessing)
   1182                 _r=1):
   1183               callbacks.on_train_batch_begin(step)
-> 1184               tmp_logs = self.train_function(iterator)
   1185               if data_handler.should_sync:
   1186                 context.async_wait()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwds)
    883 
    884       with OptionalXlaContext(self._jit_compile):
--> 885         result = self._call(*args, **kwds)
    886 
    887       new_tracing_count = self.experimental_get_tracing_count()

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in _call(self, *args, **kwds)
    922       # In this case we have not created variables on the first call. So we can
    923       # run the first trace but we should fail if variables are created.
--> 924       results = self._stateful_fn(*args, **kwds)
    925       if self._created_variables and not ALLOW_DYNAMIC_VARIABLE_CREATION:
    926         raise ValueError("Creating variables on a non-first call to a function"

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in __call__(self, *args, **kwargs)
   3036     with self._lock:
   3037       (graph_function,
-> 3038        filtered_flat_args) = self._maybe_define_function(args, kwargs)
   3039     return graph_function._call_flat(
   3040         filtered_flat_args, captured_inputs=graph_function.captured_inputs)  # pylint: disable=protected-access

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _maybe_define_function(self, args, kwargs)
   3458               call_context_key in self._function_cache.missed):
   3459             return self._define_function_with_shape_relaxation(
-> 3460                 args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3461 
   3462           self._function_cache.missed.add(call_context_key)

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _define_function_with_shape_relaxation(self, args, kwargs, flat_args, filtered_flat_args, cache_key_context)
   3380 
   3381     graph_function = self._create_graph_function(
-> 3382         args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes=relaxed_arg_shapes)
   3383     self._function_cache.arg_relaxed[rank_only_cache_key] = graph_function
   3384 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/function.py in _create_graph_function(self, args, kwargs, override_flat_arg_shapes)
   3306             arg_names=arg_names,
   3307             override_flat_arg_shapes=override_flat_arg_shapes,
-> 3308             capture_by_value=self._capture_by_value),
   3309         self._function_attributes,
   3310         function_spec=self.function_spec,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in func_graph_from_py_func(name, python_func, args, kwargs, signature, func_graph, autograph, autograph_options, add_control_dependencies, arg_names, op_return_value, collections, capture_by_value, override_flat_arg_shapes, acd_record_initial_resource_uses)
   1005         _, original_func = tf_decorator.unwrap(python_func)
   1006 
-> 1007       func_outputs = python_func(*func_args, **func_kwargs)
   1008 
   1009       # invariant: `func_outputs` contains only Tensors, CompositeTensors,

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/eager/def_function.py in wrapped_fn(*args, **kwds)
    666         # the function a weak reference to itself to avoid a reference cycle.
    667         with OptionalXlaContext(compile_with_xla):
--> 668           out = weak_wrapped_fn().__wrapped__(*args, **kwds)
    669         return out
    670 

/opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/func_graph.py in wrapper(*args, **kwargs)
    992           except Exception as e:  # pylint:disable=broad-except
    993             if hasattr(e, "ag_error_metadata"):
--> 994               raise e.ag_error_metadata.to_exception(e)
    995             else:
    996               raise

ValueError: in user code:

    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:853 train_function  *
        return step_function(self, iterator)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:842 step_function  **
        outputs = model.distribute_strategy.run(run_step, args=(data,))
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:1286 run
        return self._extended.call_for_each_replica(fn, args=args, kwargs=kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:2849 call_for_each_replica
        return self._call_for_each_replica(fn, args, kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/distribute/distribute_lib.py:3632 _call_for_each_replica
        return fn(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:835 run_step  **
        outputs = model.train_step(data)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/training.py:789 train_step
        y, y_pred, sample_weight, regularization_losses=self.losses)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/engine/compile_utils.py:201 __call__
        loss_value = loss_obj(y_t, y_p, sample_weight=sw)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py:141 __call__
        losses = call_fn(y_true, y_pred)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py:245 call  **
        return ag_fn(y_true, y_pred, **self._fn_kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/losses.py:1666 categorical_crossentropy
        y_true, y_pred, from_logits=from_logits, axis=axis)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/util/dispatch.py:206 wrapper
        return target(*args, **kwargs)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/keras/backend.py:4839 categorical_crossentropy
        target.shape.assert_is_compatible_with(output.shape)
    /opt/conda/lib/python3.7/site-packages/tensorflow/python/framework/tensor_shape.py:1161 assert_is_compatible_with
        raise ValueError("Shapes %s and %s are incompatible" % (self, other))

    ValueError: Shapes (None, 1) and (None, 4) are incompatible
```

Answer (score 0):

I took time to make your display graph make sense with my sample data.

Sample: First of all you need to create dimension output matching to your display calculations matrix see loss Fn, Optimizer, Matrix, and the network output. Then you need to create senses of predict data, they are not allowed multiple input value then I take time to make it significant as a sample. Max or Sum is significant

Sum of all Max is not significant as all priority in the my queue.

```
import os
from os.path import exists

import tensorflow as tf
import tensorflow_text as tft

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import sklearn.metrics
from sklearn.svm import SVC

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
[PhysicalDevice(name='/physical_device:GPU:0', device_type='GPU')]
None
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
physical_devices = tf.config.experimental.list_physical_devices('GPU')
assert len(physical_devices) > 0, "Not enough GPU hardware devices available"
config = tf.config.experimental.set_memory_growth(physical_devices[0], True)
print(physical_devices)
print(config)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Variables
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
list_accuracy = []

checkpoint_path = "F:\\models\\checkpoint\\" + os.path.basename(__file__).split('.')[0] + "\\TF_DataSets_01.h5"
checkpoint_dir = os.path.dirname(checkpoint_path)

if not exists(checkpoint_dir) : 
    os.mkdir(checkpoint_dir)
    print("Create directory: " + checkpoint_dir)
    
input_word = tf.constant(' \'Cause it\'s easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Slipping outta your hand into the dirt Easy as an ice cream sundae Every dancer gets a little hurt Easy as an ice cream sundae Oh, easy as an ice cream sundae ')
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
window_size = 6
dataset = dataset.map( lambda x:  tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0) ).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
dataset = dataset.batch(1)

list_word = []
label = []
vocab = [ "a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f", "g", "h", "I", "j", "k", "l", "m", "n", "o", "p", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z", "_" ]
vocab_hot = [ "ice" ]
layer = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab)
layer_hot = tf.keras.layers.StringLookup(vocabulary=vocab_hot)

for example in dataset.take(200):
    sequences_mapping_string = layer(example[0])
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 6) )
    list_word.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())

    sequences_mapping_string = tf.reduce_sum(layer_hot( example[0][0] + example[0][1] + example[0][2] ))
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 1) )
    
    label.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())
    
list_word = tf.constant(list_word, shape=(200, 1, 6, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
label = tf.constant(label, shape=(200, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_word, label))

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Class / Definition
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class MulticlassTruePositives(tf.keras.metrics.Metric):
    def __init__(self, name='multiclass_true_positives', **kwargs):
        super(MulticlassTruePositives, self).__init__(name=name, **kwargs)
        self.true_positives = self.add_weight(name='tp', initializer='zeros')

    def update_state(self, y_true, y_pred, sample_weight=None):
        y_pred = tf.reshape(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), shape=(-1, 1))
        values = tf.cast(y_true, 'int32') == tf.cast(y_pred, 'int32')
        values = tf.cast(values, 'float32')
        if sample_weight is not None:
            sample_weight = tf.cast(sample_weight, 'float32')
            values = tf.multiply(values, sample_weight)
        self.true_positives.assign_add(tf.reduce_sum(values))

    def result(self):
        return self.true_positives

    def reset_state(self):
        # The state of the metric will be reset at the start of each epoch.
        self.true_positives.assign(0.)

class MyLSTMLayer( tf.keras.layers.LSTM ):
    def __init__(self, units, return_sequences, return_state):
        super(MyLSTMLayer, self).__init__( units, return_sequences=True, return_state=False )
        self.num_units = units

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.kernel = self.add_weight("kernel",
        shape=[int(input_shape[-1]),
        self.num_units])

    def call(self, inputs):
        return tf.matmul(inputs, self.kernel)           

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Initialize
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
mycustomlayer = MyLSTMLayer( 64, True, False )
mycustomlayer_2 = MyLSTMLayer( 16, True, False )

model = tf.keras.models.Sequential([
    tf.keras.layers.InputLayer(input_shape=(6, 1)),
    tf.keras.layers.Embedding(1000, 128, input_length=1),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 6, 128 )),
    tf.keras.layers.SpatialDropout1D( rate = 0.4 ),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 6, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(strides=1, pool_size=1),
    ### LSTM
    mycustomlayer,
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 1, 1, 64 )),
    tf.keras.layers.UpSampling2D( size=(4, 4), data_format=None, interpolation='nearest' ),
    tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(16, 3, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 8, 16 )),
    tf.keras.layers.MaxPooling1D(),
    tf.keras.layers.GlobalMaxPooling1D(),
    ### LSTM
    tf.keras.layers.Reshape(( 1, 16 )),
    mycustomlayer_2,
    tf.keras.layers.Dropout(0.3),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(128, activation="relu"),
    tf.keras.layers.Flatten(),
    tf.keras.layers.Dense(1),
    
], name="MyModelClassification")

model.build()
model.summary()

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Callback
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
class PerformanceVisualizationCallback(tf.keras.callbacks.Callback):
    def __init__(self, model, test_data, image_dir):
        super().__init__()
        self.model = model
        self.test_data = test_data
        self.test_data = tf.constant( self.test_data, shape=(20, 1, 6, 1) )

        os.makedirs(image_dir, exist_ok=True)
        self.image_dir = image_dir

    def on_epoch_end(self, epoch, logs={}):
        y_pred = tf.constant(self.model.predict(self.test_data[0])).numpy()
        y_true = self.test_data[1]             
        y_pred_class = tf.math.argmax(y_pred, axis=1).numpy()
        
        clf = SVC(random_state=0)
        clf.fit(tf.constant( self.test_data, shape=(20, 6) ).numpy(), tf.cast( tf.linspace( 0, 19, 20, name='linspace', axis=0 ), dtype=tf.int64 ).numpy())
        predictions = clf.predict(tf.constant( self.test_data, shape=(20, 6) ).numpy())
        
        cm = sklearn.metrics.confusion_matrix(
                [tf.math.argmax(self.test_data[1], axis=1).numpy()[0], tf.math.argmax(self.test_data[2], axis=1).numpy()[0], 
                tf.math.argmax(self.test_data[3], axis=1).numpy()[0], tf.math.argmax(self.test_data[4], axis=1).numpy()[0], tf.math.argmax(self.test_data[5], axis=1).numpy()[0]], 
                [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], labels=clf.classes_)
        disp = sklearn.metrics.ConfusionMatrixDisplay(confusion_matrix=cm, display_labels=clf.classes_)
        disp.plot()
        plt.show()
        # fig.savefig(os.path.join(self.image_dir, f'confusion_matrix_epoch_{epoch}'))

        clf = sklearn.svm.SVC(random_state=0)
        clf.fit(tf.constant( self.test_data, shape=(20, 6) ).numpy(), tf.linspace( 0, 19, 20, name='linspace', axis=0 ).numpy())
        
        if (epoch <= 2):
            list_accuracy.append( logs['accuracy'] )
        
        
        if (epoch == 2):
            fpr, tpr, thresholds = sklearn.metrics.roc_curve([0, 0, 1, 1], [0, list_accuracy[0], list_accuracy[1], list_accuracy[2]])
            roc_auc = sklearn.metrics.auc(fpr, tpr)
            display = sklearn.metrics.RocCurveDisplay(fpr=fpr, tpr=tpr, roc_auc=roc_auc, estimator_name='example estimator')
            display.plot()
            plt.show()
        # fig.savefig(os.path.join(self.image_dir, f'roc_curve_epoch_{epoch}'))

list_word = []
label = []

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensors( tf.strings.bytes_split(input_word) )
test_dataset = test_dataset.map( lambda x:  tft.sliding_window(x, width=window_size, axis=0) ).flat_map(tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices)
test_dataset = test_dataset.batch(1)

for example in test_dataset.take(20):
    sequences_mapping_string = layer(example[0])
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 6) )
    list_word.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())

    sequences_mapping_string = tf.reduce_sum(layer_hot( example[0][0] + example[0][1] + example[0][2] ))
    sequences_mapping_string = tf.constant( sequences_mapping_string, shape=(1, 1) )
    
    label.append(sequences_mapping_string.numpy())
    
list_word = tf.constant(list_word, shape=(20, 1, 6, 1), dtype=tf.int64)
label = tf.constant(label, shape=(20, 1, 1, 1), dtype=tf.int64)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((list_word, label))   

performance_viz_cbk = PerformanceVisualizationCallback(
                                       model=model,
                                       test_data=list_word,
                                       image_dir='c:\perorfmance_charts')

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Optimizer
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
optimizer = tf.keras.optimizers.SGD(
    learning_rate=0.000001,
    momentum=0.5,
    nesterov=True,
    name='SGD',
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Loss Fn
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""                               
lossfn = tf.keras.losses.BinaryCrossentropy(
    from_logits=False,
    reduction=tf.keras.losses.Reduction.AUTO,
    name='sparse_categorical_crossentropy'
)

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Model Summary
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
# Report the AUC of a model outputting a probability.
model.compile(optimizer=optimizer, loss=lossfn,
              metrics=['accuracy', tf.keras.metrics.AUC(), MulticlassTruePositives()])

"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: FileWriter
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
if exists(checkpoint_path) :
    model.load_weights(checkpoint_path)
    print("model load: " + checkpoint_path)
    input("Press Any Key!")
    
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
: Training
"""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""""
history = model.fit(dataset, batch_size=100, epochs=3, callbacks=[performance_viz_cbk] )
```